# Why does Stack Overflow order the questions I've asked (listed in my profile) by date where other Stack Exchange sites order by upvote?

Tags: support, profile-page, asking-questions, question-order

On Stack Overflow, the questions in my profile are ordered by asking date (which I like) with the most recently asked question first, but on other Stack Exchange sites, (e.g. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)) the questions that I've asked (as listed in my profile) are ordered by the number of upvotes.

I find this annoying, because the most-recently asked question appears at the bottom of the list which ends up being on the next page. Is there some profile option that I've missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the default is to order by votes, which is why you see that on most sites. At some point in the past you probably clicked one of the other sort tabs on SO:

[image: Screenshot of the sort tabs]

The site will remember the last sort you used, and use it in the future automatically

Comment: Bah, I missed the four boxes to the right!  Thanks.  I'll accept your answer as soon as the question gods let me... 12 minutes from now.